# Is there a way to force a specific media query breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Lets say I have css with the styles

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
 ...styles go here
}
```

And I want to force the page to adhere to that specific breakpoint's styles, as in, I want to make it so "the width is always > 640px" regardless of the actual window size. Is there a way to do that in the html, css, or via javascript?

I can't alter the original stylesheet, although I can load in an additional stylesheet or run custom code, but I'd rather not have to essentially copy and past all the styles for this breakpoint if I can avoid that

Comment: Forgive me if I'm on the wrong path here, but where you're saying `(min-width: 640px)`, that's just telling the media query to only activate when that's true.

Comment: just remove the media query line "`@media screen and (min-width: 640px)`" so the style is always applied...

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/inspect-and-trigger-css-media-queries/

Comment: To paraphrase the question:
1. You have an external stylesheet which you cannot alter, but you can load additional stylesheets if needed.
2. The original stylesheet above has a series of styles based on a particular breakpoint.
3. And you'd like to _only use the breakpoint_ styles by somehow telling the browser that "this is the current viewport size" (and ignore the actual window size).

Am I understanding you correctly? If so, I'm very curious about the potential solution here.

Comment: @AnasAbdullahAl like i said, i can't remove the styling from the sheet. It's a system with a page with default styling, so I can load in an external sheet to override styles. I would just rather not having to essentially copy and paste all the styles in that media query block

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to duplicate through JavaScript the media query rules for that certain `CSSStyleSheet` by matching specific `conditionText`, something like this:

```
const styles = [];

for (const CSSStyleSheet of document.styleSheets)
    for (const rule of CSSStyleSheet.cssRules)
        if (rule instanceof CSSMediaRule &&
            rule.conditionText === 'screen and (min-width: 640px)') {
            for (const r of rule.cssRules)
                styles.push([CSSStyleSheet, r.cssText]);
        }

styles.forEach(([style, rule]) => style.insertRule(rule));
```

Comment: This would work if all the breakpoints were for that exact width, but i think there are a number of them for various sizes, but I could probably come up with conditionText checks that include all of them for the desired size

Comment: If they differ only by size then a replace will do that: `rule.conditionText.replace(/\d+/, '0') === 'screen and (min-width: 0px)'`